# Setting up Beats audio on HP Pavilion M6

Tags: sound, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion m6-1054sa laptop, with a Beats subwoofer on the bottom. The normal laptop speakers work fine under Ubuntu but the Beats speaker(s?) does not. Anyone know how to get this working? Here's my `lspci` output, if it helps.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames XT/GL [Radeon HD 7600M Series] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
07:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Gentoo forum describes their solution, I do not think it is ideal since it requires a recompile, but I think you should be able to follow. their instructions and adapt them to Ubuntu (depending on your skill level of course).

Gentoo: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-922794-start-0.html

Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1019127

Comment: these are solutions for internal sd card readers... ?